# How to customize swing UI design in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm making a project in swing in Netbeans. My designing part code is too large in `initComponents()`.I know that Java has a 64k limit on the size of methods but swing by default designing `initComponents()` taking more than 64k. So, how can I make a new method who takes automatic design code inside this method same as `initComponents()`.

Comment: One can design panel forms. For repetitions in design consider arrays/lists instead (programmatic design based on a GUI design).

Comment: Sorry, i dont undestand . Could you explain?

Comment: If you have 10 times `JEditField name1-10` you might just as easy change that to `JEditField[] names = new JEditField[10]` (Programming required). Alternatively one can use several JPanels, everyone with its own GUI form. In the main form one can add panels with custom creation code.

Answer (score 1):

In swing applications NetBeans add the following line for **Generated Code**s.

```
//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
```

This prevents user from editing the code. So...

1. Finish your design completely.
2. Locate the `*.java` file(source file) and open it using a normal
   text editor.
3. Find the method `initComponents()` and delete the above line. Now
   you can edit `initComponents()` method within NetBeans.

[image: init]

> **This will crash the NetBeans GUI builder. So finish your design completely.**

Create a new method. Split your design code into two. Half in `initComponents()` and the other half in your new method. Call your new method inside the constructor after `initComponents()`.

```
private void design(){
    //your design code
}

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    design();
}
```

Comment: but when i design it automatically goes inside initcomponents()

Comment: No problem... after `initcomponents()` it'll come to your method

Comment: how can i customize designing code inside new method because it automatically goes to  initcomponent()

Comment: is any other solutions because it's very time consuming ? and thanks for reply

Comment: Nope. you can't edit generated codes without deleting that line. and all design codes are written there...

Comment: ok i do this. If any problem occur then I'll ask you. if you don't mind could you give me your email id please?

Comment: If an error occurs we can continue this in StackOverflow Chat